# How do professional games avoid showing pixel seams in adjacent mesh boundaries due to decimal imprecision?

Tags: vertex, gpu, mesh, seams

Graphics cards are mathematically imprecise.

So when some meshes are joined by their borders, the graphics card often makes mistakes and decides that some pixels at the seam represent neither object, and unwanted pixels appear.

It's a natural behaviour on all graphics cards. How are such worries avoided in Pro Games? Batching? Shaders? Different tangent vectors? Merging? Overlaping seams? Dark backgrounds? Extra vertices at borders? Z precision? Camera distance tweaks?

Screencap of a fix that ended up not working:
[image]

Comment: anti-aliasing will probably fix this.

Comment: Professional game engines dont have seams in landscapes regardless of  anti-aliasing :) It does help, however even 16AA doesnt totally fix it, it's more of a bandage applied to the issue after it happened, and aa is costly performance wise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modern graphics APIs are very careful about specifying how rasterization of triangles that share edges will be done in order to avoid overlapping fragments and missing fragments.

Fabien Giesen mentions one of these rules in his article series on the graphics pipeline, cited here:

> you need to have tie-breaking rules to ensure that for any pair of triangles sharing an edge, no pixel near that edge will ever be skipped or rasterized twice. D3D and OpenGL both use the so-called “top-left” fill rule; the details are explained in the respective manuals. I won’t talk about it here except to note that with this kind of integer rasterizer, it boils down to subtracting 1 from the constant term on some edges during triangle setup. That makes it guaranteed watertight, no fuss at all

An example is Direct3D 10's [Rasterization Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc627092%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documented in public on MSDN.

This requires that your vertices (and thus edges) are exactly coinciding which is not a problem inside individual meshes and terrain chunks.

When it comes to the XZ grid of terrain chunks, you can often organize your computation of grid positions such that they perfectly agree when you move chunks around. When transitioning between LoD levels, most techniques apply skirts or a spreading-out pattern along the edges to avoid T-junctions and the interpolation differences those have.

You may want to reconsider the use of terms like 'mistakes' and 'imprecise'. They do exactly what they're told, and floating point arithmetic rules are deterministic. Misuse, operation ordering or misspecification of what you tolerate is what causes problems, not spurious cosmic rays that mutate results.

Comment: Thanks so much, rasterization rules, brilliant. Are you sure that the single precision of graphics card and openGL framework are able to guarantee that there are no graphics errors at seams? If so, it would appear that Unity3d therefore is not implementing a rasterization that correctly can show every pixel, because i have printed the edge vertices and they are the same. What kind of rasterizer can unity be using, that causes pixel errors? the shared vertices are all of type: **(-100000.0, 13990.1, 112500.0)   (-100000.0, 13990.1, 112500.0)**

Comment: If you wish to compare numbers you should compare their bitwise form, as textual representation can either differ between different printing methods or be the same for different numbers.

Comment: Thankyou, I understand, i have to compare their 1101101 equivalent. I found the article that you quote, it sais that D3D uses the top left fill rule, therefore unity3d must be implementing it. thanks

Comment: Note that this "no pixels will be missed" system is only guaranteed to work for *shared edges*.  If you have a T junction (for example, a wide rectangle over two squares), then you're not guaranteed complete coverage of the pixels along that edge between the rectangle and squares, since they don't share an edge.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, I have found out why unity3d was causing this problem while printing that the vertices sent to the graphics card had the same world position. the solution is not online and it took me a year to find out so contact me privately if you are a company :) if your game engine is doing this and has the same vertex information is, I know at least 2 fixes! Thanks! I can confirm that Trevor and Lars are completely correct. The graphic card is rock solid. the game engine isn't!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the seam imprecision increased with distance from origin.

Because the further an object is from origin, the bigger mistakes occur in single precision floating point maths, obj positions are rounded and sent to graphics card, and their vertices are different in graphics card, even if they are whole numers and mathematically and logically the same...

If you keep all objects on origin, and instead you reassign the VERTEX POSITIONS to new positions, all the vertices in the graphics card will be the same because no different roundings from different obj positions: all obj positions and mesh positions to the graphics will be the same and there will be no errors.